# Why is it advised not to use Ionic framework for creating webapps?

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, ionic-framework

I read comments and advice about Ionic framework being used mainly for Hybrid apps (via phonegap). What is the reason that it is not recommended for a web-app on mobile?

Answer (score 1):

Inoic built as a hybrid mobile app platform, it's purpose is to wrap Cordova and it's device proxy abilities and implement it using angular and ui-router. The UI components are mobile suited and would not fit a large browser screen.

In order to achieve that in web development you can just use Angular + Angular UI + Bootstrap, plus you can create the data module to be loosely coupled from the ionic app and share it among both platforms